# Клиент-серверные приложения

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте. Прошу помочь в литературе (книги, разделы книг, статьи) по написанию клиент-серверных приложений на С++. Чтобы было кратко и очень доступно. Все что мне надо - передать зашифрованный текст и принять для расшифровки. Для такой задачи лень изучать подробности. Может есть готовые библиотеки, или скачать такие возможно. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что необходимо.

1. Библиотека работы с сетью и умение работать с ней. Рекомендую [Самоучитель игры на WINSOCK](http://citforum.ru/book/cook/winsock.shtml)
2. Протокол шифрования. Самое простое: каждый байт входного сообщения поXORить с байтом ключа. Расшифровка такая же.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень полезная статейка: кратко, доступно, в тему и по делу.
ps Шифровать мне самому нужно. Предмет у меня такой появился - криптография) Препод требует организацию клиент-серверных приложений. Но, в любом случае спасибо - буду иметь ввиду и этот метод.

Answer (score 0):

Шон Уолтон "Создание сетевых приложений в среде Linux" - использую как справочник.